# Quick sort timecomplexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is time complexity of quick sort algorithm when pivot is taken as middle element(order of elements are random) ,is it O(n^2).

For example time complexity for
5 7 1 3 9 6 4

Where pivot is 3.

Answer (score 2):

Quick sort is `O(n lg(n))` in average case, and `O(n^2)` in worse.
Selecting middle element does not determine which case do you fall into.
Optimal is selecting median element.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort